# Garbage top results for "PHP self post example", no canonical example

Tags: discussion, canonical

The top 3 questions I found from Google about "PHP self post"/"PHP self post example" were these:

[How do I make a PHP form that submits to self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/php-submit-to-self)

[php form action php self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862735/php-form-action-php-self)

[HTML Form Submit To Self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009910/html-form-submit-to-self)

All three have a lot of views - people are searching on this topic, they land on these questions, but are they really getting much help from them?

All three look like bad questions - they have a misleading title that makes you think you will get a canonical example of how to do it, when in fact they ask why the OP's failed attempt didn't work. The answers are usually about how the OP should fix his attempt.

Should something be done about it, and what? Should I try to improve one of the question, or create a brand new one? Should I mark the others as duplicates to the new/fixed questions?

Answer (score 5):

That has happened to me a few times recently. It even [led me to write a canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632725/how-do-i-log-a-user-out-when-they-close-their-browser-or-tab-in-asp-net-mvc/23633068%2323633068) so that others wouldn't encounter the bad questions.

Unfortunately, the best you can do is to find a canonical answer for that subject or write one to one of those existing questions. With the amount of traffic that tag gets, it's not unreasonable to think a well written answer would get plenty of up votes, helping to push the less complete answers out of the way.